# Can Excel retain 2 paste special options for a linked cell?

Tags: excel, paste

I have multiple Excel sheets with data elements and formatting that I would like to link.

This data is on Sheet 1:

[image]

I can copy the fields, 'Test Data' and 'More Test Data'.
Then paste the data using 'Paste Link' to link the data fields so if I change one of the fields the other linked field also changes.

I'd also like to include the cell formatting with the linked contents. So if I change the 'Test Data' field by selecting the Styles-Good.  This formatting also changes in the linked data field.

I can select the linked paste option then the formatting option and the linked cell changes to the original cell's formatting.  Shown below:

[image]

But when I change the original cell's formatting, the linked cell does not update:

[image]

Is there anyway that I can link the contents of a cell AND the formatting of a cell to another cell so when the contents OR the formatting changes, it is updated in the linked cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use paste.special to paste the value or function and you can paste the formats only.

however a linked cell won't update the formats but WILL update the cells contents of the linked cell when the source cell contents are changed either as a value or the result of a function.

To get a linked cell to update formats you will need vba.

Comment: Thank you!
Could you have any links that I could review to write the VBA script?

Comment: @GloriaSantin You could have used `Linked Picture` instead, that would have done what you are looking for.

Comment: @GloriaSantin or better one use `Camera Tool`, only you need to select the data and click on the `Camera Tool` try to place it in the `QAT`, doesnt needs any changes gets updated quickly when there is a change in the source, very helpful while creating summary dashboards for data analysis!

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I I like the LInked Picture better.  Is there any way to attach the picture to the cells?

Comment: @GloriaSantin unfortunately **placing in the cell** will have no effect as it will completely become a different object and the linking feature with image dies immediately. It also does the same when used with `Camera Tool` and **place in the cell**. As long as it there over the cell it will work! And the reason you can see on your own, select the linked pic and see in the formula bar it will show you a formula of the range but when you make it **place in the cell** by right clicking the object the link expires and the formula bar will read as `Picture`